# Install IntelliJ IDEA on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, intellij-idea, installation

I try to install IntelliJ IDEA on Ubuntu, using a guide but I have some difficulties.

I know the basics of using a terminal. So the file `idea-IU-141.178.9` needs to move to `/opt/idea`. I use `sudo -i` to get in the root, otherwise permission is denied. But when I try to move the file, it keeps giving me the error that the file can't be found.

However when I reopen my terminal and use `ls` command, the file is shown in the `~` directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `sudo -i`, your current directory change to `/root`. Use full path to the file that you want to move:

```
sudo -i
mv /home/myusername/myfile /opt/idea/
exit
```

or move the file with `sudo`:

```
sudo mv myfile /opt/idea/
```